# What does Prolog do if you X = f(X)?

Tags: prolog, occurs-check

What does it mean in Prolog comparing a predicate to an unbound variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result of the `X = f(X)` goal depends on the Prolog implementation, In some systems, as Carlo pointed out in his answer, the result can be controlled by a user settable flag. The unification predicate, `(=)/2`, may be implemented with or without what's called the *occurs check*. This check verifies if a variable in one operand occurs in a sub-term in the other operand. When the unification predicate implements this check, the goal `X = f(X)` fails. But, for performance reasons, the unification predicate is often implemented without this check. The ISO Prolog standard specifies an alternative unification predicate, aptly named `unify_with_occurs_check/2`, that can be used when goals such as this one can lead to trouble.

Nowadays, several implementations support the *cyclic terms*, also known as *rational terms*, that are created by goals such as `X = f(X)`. These include CxProlog, ECLiPSe, SICStus Prolog, SWI-Prolog, and YAP. Note, however, that the level of support for rational terms varies across system. The minimal support will be (1) to be able to create rational terms (without a stack overflow!), (2) to be able to unify two rational terms, and (3) to be able to print query bindings that include rational terms in a non-ambiguous way. With these three features you can e.g. implement *coinductive logic programming*, which is useful for several classes of problems.

Answer (score 7):

In Prolog, [(=)/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28%3D%29/2) it not a comparison, but a fundamental operation, called [unification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_%28computer_science%29).

The expression you show in your question title, if called when X is a free variable, will create a *cyclic* term. In SWI-Prolog

```
?- X=f(X),write(X).
@(S_1,[S_1=f(S_1)])
X = f(X).
```

Cyclic terms are problematic to handle, usually are created by programming errors: the behaviour of SWI-Prolog (and others) can be controlled using a global flag, see [occurs_check](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=flags#flag:occurs_check).