# How is Prolog matching "X = father(X)"?

Tags: prolog, unification

In Prolog I entered following query to check if they match:

```
?- father(X) = X.
```

Prolog responded with this:

```
X = father(X).
```

But in the book it is written that Prolog should respond like this:

```
X = father(father(father(father(father(father(...)))))))))).
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: The answer depends on your prolog system, but it always depends on the system's respective recursion detection.

Comment: See also [What does Prolog do if you `X = f(X)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29709501/what-does-prolog-do-if-you-x-fx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short story

The Prolog book is probably old.

The Prolog interpreter is most likely a lot newer. Also, your interpreter is smart enough to write a cyclic term very compactly.

#### Longer story

At the heart of Prolog's execution mechanism lies syntactic 
[unification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_%28computer_science%29) of terms. Unification has similarities with [pattern matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_matching). However, with pattern matching variables may occur on *at most one side* of the equation sign. With unification variables may occur on *both* sides.

This makes it possible to construct [cyclic terms](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=cyclic), i.e., terms that contain *themselves* as a subterm.

It is possible to explicitly prevent these terms from being created during unification by performing an "[occurs check](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occurs_check)"---causing unification to fail in these cases. The Prolog builtin predicate [`unify_with_occurs_check/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=unify_with_occurs_check/2) does as its name suggests and fails in such cases.

---

Your initial query:

```
?- X = father(X).
X = father(X).            % unification succeeds, but creates cyclic term
```

Using the builtin predicate `unify_with_occurs_check/2`:

```
?- unify_with_occurs_check(X,father(X)).
false.                    % "occur check" causes unification failure
```

Let's set the flag `occurs_check` to make **all** unifications have an "occurs check":

```
?- set_prolog_flag(occurs_check,true).
true.                     % all following unifications will do "occurs check"

?- X = father(X).         % the exact same query succeeded above.
false.                    % here it fails because of the "occurs check"
```